# Why doesn't useState work with deeply nested objects and arrays in them?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my use case I have an array of `characters`, each `character` has multiple `builds`, and each `build` has a `weapons` string, and `artifacts` string. I'm making a tool to select portions of each string and assign them to a value, e.g. assigning index `3-49` of weapons to a specific weapon.

```js
const [characterIndices, setCharacterIndices] = useState<
    { builds: { weaponIndices: SE[]; artifactSetIndices: SE[] }[] }[]
  >([
    ...characters.map((char) => {
      return {
        builds: [
          ...char.builds.map((_build) => {
            return {
              weaponIndices: [],
              artifactSetIndices: [],
            };
          }),
        ],
      };
    }),
  ]);
```

The `SE` type is as follows:

```js
type SE = { start: number; end: number; code: string };
//start and end are the respective start and end of selected text
//code is the specific artifact or weapon
```

The `weaponIndices` and `artifactSetIndices` basically hold the start and end of selected text in a readonly textarea.
I have a function to add a `SE` to either `weaponIndices` or `artifactSetIndices`:

```js
const addSE = (
    type: "weaponIndices" | "artifactSetIndices",
    { start, end, code }: SE,
    characterIndex: number,
    buildIndex: number
  ) => {
    let chars = characterIndices;
    chars[characterIndex].builds[buildIndex][type].push({ start, end, code });
    setCharacterIndices((_prev) => chars);
    console.log(characterIndices[characterIndex].builds[buildIndex][type]);
  };
```

I think that using a console log after using a set function isn't recommended, but it does show what it's intended to the `weaponIndices`, or `artifactSetIndices` after an entry is added.
Passing the `addSE` function alongside `characterIndices` to a separate component, and using `addSE`, does print the respective indices after adding an entry, but the component's rendering isn't updated.

It only shows up when I "soft reload" the page, when updating the files during the `create-react-app` live reload via `npm run start`.

In case you are confused about what the data types are, I've made a github repo, at https://github.com/ChrisMGeo/ght-indexer/tree/main/src at `src/data.json`. That JSON file describes what the character data looks like, including the `builds`, and each build's `weapons` and `artifacts`(called `artifact_sets` in the `JSON`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me you are not updating the state at all.
Here you are just storing the same object reference that you already have in state into a new variable `chars`.

`let chars = characterIndices;`

`chars` now holds reference to a same object as `characterIndices`.

Here you are mutating that same object

`chars[characterIndex].builds[buildIndex][type].push({ start, end, code });`

And here you are updating the state to the same object that is already in the state. Notice that no state update here occurs.

`setCharacterIndices((_prev) => chars);`

Object you have in state is mutated, but you did not "change" the value of the state, thus no component re-render.

What you could maybe do is create a copy of the object, mutate that and update the state. just change `chars` assignment like this:

```
 let chars = {...characterIndices};
```

Answer (score 1):

React often compares values using `Object.is()` only to a single level of nesting (the tested object and its children).

It will not re-render if the parent is found equal, or if all the children are found equal.

React then considers that nothing has changed.

In your implementation, even the first top-level check will immediately fail, since `Object.is(before, after)` will return true.

You could use an Immutable objects approach to eliminate this concern when setting a new state (either directly through spreading values or with a support library such as Immer).

For example instead of setting the values within the object...

```
myObj.key = newChildObj
```

...you would make a new object, which preserves many of the previous values.

```
myObj === {...myObj, key: newChildObj}
```

This means that every changed object tree is actually a different object (with only the bits that haven't changed being preserved).

To read more about this see https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-effect-of-shallow-equality-in-react-85ae0287960c